# Magento 2 product grid admin panel not showing the special price value

Tags: magento2, price, products, cost

I'm using a Magento 2.4.0 installation, and I've added `special price` and `cost` to my product grid in `Products / Inventory / Catalog`.

Now I have the `special price` and `cost` into the grid, but both show `0.00`, even if the field is filled and showing when editing the single product and checking the advanced pricing.

Any suggestion to get those shown?

Comment: Have you doing the re-indexing one's set above things?

Comment: Yes.. run ``php bin/magento indexer:reindex`` command once and check result

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have already tried to do that, and still nothing, shows same "0.00", and the values and dates are filled.

Comment: Try saving the product and check it that work

Comment: @NileshDubey what do you mean, edit the product then save it? Already tried, and nothing, the data shows in advanced pricing fields, but not in the product grid. Curious thing is that if I leave the fields empty, product feed fields are empty aswell, if I enter a value, then product grid field are 0.

Answer (score 1):

You added a Price
You added a Cost
You added a Special price

If you havent added a price it would probably go to 0? Could you check?

Comment: Yes, there is also the price, the normal price, and that appears correctly, but the other 2 not at all, those are added from advanced pricing.

Comment: Can you check logging in var/log?

Comment: Sure, just opened backend and checked catalog, here is what I get into hosting logs: 2022-01-04 17:47:52 UTC [apache][authz_core:error] [pid 45349] [client 35.214.76.254:54914] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/u2-hr4ay48xzgmd/www/mywebsitename.com/public_html/app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Special price should be lesser than the actual cost of the product because a special price is a discounted price of the product according to several criteria, such as quality, quantity, the time frame of purchase, and type of customer.
[image]

Now make changes accordingly and run the below command in Magento 2.4 root directory

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento c:c
```

More info: [docs.magento](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/pricing-advanced.html)

Comment: Tried this aswell, still nothing, shows same 0.00 in products grid for both fields.

Comment: Did u find the cause of this? Facing same issue in 2.4.3